# Header information getting lost in POST response

Tags: ruby

In a ruby POST call I am expecting some custom header named 'Authentication-Token', which is received when called from any other REST client. But when called from ruby script I am getting all headers except this required header.
Below is the code

```
    require 'net/http'
    require 'json'
    require 'uri'
    uri = URI.parse('http://ashish-1:9090/csm/login')
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
    request.set_form_data({"username" => 'test', "password" => 'test'})
    request.add_field("Authentication-Token", "")
    request.add_field("Authorization", "")
    request.add_field("Content-Type", "application/json")
    response = http.request(request)
    puts response
    puts response.code
    puts "Headers: #{response.to_hash}" #prints all headers except Authentication-Token
    puts response["session-id"] # get printed
    puts response["Authentication-Token"] # blank
```

Any idea what is missing?

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: you should also post the server side code as well..

Comment: It's up to the server to set in the response headers. Why do you think the server should echo everything you sent in the request?

Comment: In the server after authentication we are setting the 'Authentication-Token' header in response with some value. Which needs to be passed in each subsequent request. Product is working well in UI and REST client. Writing ruby script for some of the flow needs login first and then this token needs to be provided with every request.